# android- How to make all screen scrollable with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

I have a ViewPager and it has 2 Fragments. In Fragments I have a RecyclerView that show images. Above of ViewPager there are other views. I want this: When I scroll down RecyclerView in ViewPager other Views should be hidden up and recyclerview should be expand. Just like Instagram Profile Page. This is xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- a few views(Profile imageView etc.) -->

 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabInlineLabel="true" />


        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Of course I tried to use ScrollView, NestedScrollView and CoordinatorLayout but none of them worked.**